# Problems installing tensorflow in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pip, pycharm

I want to install the latest stable tensorflow package (v2.0.0) to Python 3.8.1 (64 bit) for using it with PyCharm 2019.3.1. I'm using the pip 19.3.1.

I tried to install tensorflow from the Windows 10 command line with

```
pip install tensorflow
```

but I got the error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I tried it directly with PyCharm in Settings --> Project Interpreter --> Add, but I got the same error.

After reading some older posts here, I tried another version https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.
With pip it installs the old package, but PyCharm shows nothing. Even when I open a new VirtEnv and import all global packages, it doesn't work.

I learned, that many people seem to have similar problems in the past. Any ideas how to install the latests tensorflow package in PyCharm?

Or maybe you know a better IDE instead? I tried the Anaconda distribution, but I uninstalled it because it's very slow and doesn't find a many things it wants to download (error 404).

Comment: You can try miniconda or virtual environments.

Comment: try pip3 install tensorflow

Comment: pip3 generates the same error. I installed miniconda, and the virtual environment let me install tensorflow. But how can I access it with PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the origins of the problem. One thing was a bad proxy setting, the other one was an unsupported SSL connection or certificate.

I added the DOS environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. I also set them in the `.condarc` file in my user directory.

Then I had to disable the SSL settings for installation by entering `conda config --set ssl_verify no` before using pip or conda.

After doing this I was able to add environments in conda and I also could use them in PyCharm. It took me 4 days to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow does not currently support Python 3.8, so this is why it shows no available versions (there are no official wheels for py3.8). You should downgrade Python to 3.7, where it should work with no issues.

Comment: You are right. Python versions equal or above 3.8 seem not work with tensorflow.